# PHP Api Json array?

Tags: php, arrays

How do you retrieve keys from a array such as this?
Im very confused.

```
<?php
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://completion.amazon.com/search/complete?search-alias=aps&client=amazon-search-ui&mkt=1&q=facebook");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
print_r(json_decode($result));//return amazone autocomplete suggestion
```

**RESULT:**

```
Array ( [0] => facebook [1] => Array ( [0] => facebook [1] => facebook messenger [2] => facebook app [3] => facebook.com [4] => facebook login welcome to facebook [5] => facebook gift card [6] => facebook log in [7] => facebook for dummies [8] => facebook marketing [9] => facebook messenger for blackberry 10 ) [2] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [nodes] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [name] => Apps & Games [alias] => mobile-apps ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [name] => Gift Cards [alias] => gift-cards ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [name] => Books [alias] => stripbooks ) ) ) [1] => stdClass Object ( ) [2] => stdClass Object ( ) [3] => stdClass Object ( ) [4] => stdClass Object ( ) [5] => stdClass Object ( ) [6] => stdClass Object ( ) [7] => stdClass Object ( ) [8] => stdClass Object ( ) [9] => stdClass Object ( ) ) [3] => Array ( ) )
```

Comment: I am trying to get the values from the JSON response from the API

http://completion.amazon.com/search/complete?search-alias=aps&client=amazon-search-ui&mkt=1&q=facebook

Answer (score 0):

use for each statment :

```
foreach ($result as $key => $value)
      foreach ($result[$key] as $k => $va)
           echo $key, $k, $val;
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to get the search suggestions based on "facebook". After you `json_decode` the response, These will be in `$result[1]` as you can see in your `print_r` output. They are in an array, which you can iterate over like this:

```
$result = json_decode($result);

foreach ($result[1] as $suggestion) {
    echo "$suggestion<br>";  // or whatever you want to do with it
}
```